# Distributing .pyc files versus .py files for a commercial, closed-source python module

Tags: python

Personally I think it's better to distribute .py files as these will then be compiled by the end-user's own python, which may be more patched.

What are the pros and cons of distributing .pyc files versus .py files for a commercial, closed-source python module?

In other words, are there any compelling reasons to distribute .pyc files?

Edit: In particular, if the .py/.pyc is accompanied by a DLL/SO module which is compiled against a certain version of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your proprietary bits are inside a binary DLL or SO, then there's no real value in making an interface layer a `.pyc` (as opposed to a `.py`). You can drop that all together or distribute it as an uncompiled python file. I don't know of any reasons to distribute compiled python files. In many cases, build environments treat them as stale byproducts and clean them out so your program might disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that there are open source and proprietary de-compilers to convert Python byte code to Python source. One such example would be [Mysterie's uncompyle2](https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2)

Moreover, **`.pyc` files are not cross version safe**, so there are more trouble than benefit in distributing `.pyc` over `.py`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware.  I guess I am really asking does anyone have a compelling reason to distribute .pyc files?  I can't think of any!

Comment: @bluedog: Please read the last line of my answer. It should probably answer your question.

Comment: That is an excellent point.  I should mention that the module in question is accompanied by a DLL/SO which is, of course, tied to one version of Python... In case this is relevant.